# How to test if passed in datetime (GMT) is within 5 minutes of time?

Tags: c#, datetime

In my service endpoint, I get a string representation of a GMT time.

I have to validate that the passed in time is within 5 minutes of the current time.

How should I be doing this?

```
        bool result = false;
        DateTime gmt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(passedInGmtAsString, out gmt))
        {
            DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

            result  = ??
        }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx

Comment: Careful, there are nuance to how `DateTime.TryParse` works.  What does your input string actually look like? Please give an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your parse the passed in date to an appropriate format, you can use the `DateTime.Subtract` method to determine the difference, e.g.

```
var minutes = utcNow.Subtract(gmt).TotalMinutes
```

Comment: You want to use `TotalMinutes`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott If the difference is 63 minutes, Minutes will be 3.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: no, `TotalMinutes` will give 65 when you have a difference of 1 hour, 5 minutes, whereas minutes will give you 5.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight-forward solution seems to be something like

```
result = Math.Abs((gmt - utcNow).TotalMinutes) < 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Result = ((DateTime.UtcNow - gmt).TotalMinutes <= 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    bool result = false;
    DateTime gmt;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(passedInGmtAsString, out gmt))
    {
        DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

        result  = (gmt - utcNow).TotalMinutes <= 5;
    }
```

Comment: what if `gmt - utcNow` has `Hours==1, Minutes==1`? You will get true for that case.

Comment: I see that now...it's what @cadrell0 was referring to.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result via

```
result = TimeSpan.Compare(gmt.Subtract(utcNow), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)) == -1;
```

[Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/system.timespan.compare.aspx) will return `-1` if the first timespan (the difference) is shorter than the second one (5 minutes).